# Could a object be moved if this is no `copy constructor` for the class?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor, move-constructor

Could a object be moved if this is no `copy constructor` for the class?In another word, is it legal that a class has `move constructor` whereas its `copy constructor` is marked as deleted.If it's ok, does it go againt the rule of three, rule of five?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly legal.

Think about e.g. [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), which is indeed movable but not copyable.

Comment: Does it go againt the rule of three, rule of five?

Comment: @sunshilong369 Those rules are more of a guideline... Besides, if you have an explicitly deleted copy-constructor you do have a copy-constructor. If you also have a destructor and assignment operators (the copy-assignment operator should be deleted as well) you are in a way following the rule of five.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.What do you mean by "if you have an explicitly deleted copy-constructor you do have a copy-constructor.”?If it is deleted, how can i have a copy-constructor?Could you explain that in more detail?

Comment: @sunshilong369 Basically the rule is that you need to *declare* a copy-constructor. It doesn't matter if it's defined (implemented), marked as default, or marked as deleted, as long as it's declared for the class. A declared copy-constructor, even if deleted, will be part of overload resolution, and of overload resolution finds it then you have it.

Comment: I think i could understand your reply to some degree.Thank you for the clarification.As per the documentation aforemetioned, which says that:"The class satisfies the requirements of MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable, but not the requirements of either CopyConstructible or CopyAssignable." It does not state that the copy constructor must be deleted.So there could be copy constructor for `std::unique` class.Am i right?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` has a deleted implicitly-declared copy constructor, because it has a move constructor. [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

Comment: @Caleth Quote:"T has a user-defined move constructor or move assignment operator (this condition only causes the implicitly-declared, not the defaulted, copy constructor to be deleted)." What does it mean by "this condition only causes the implicitly-declared, not the defaulted, copy constructor to be deleted"? Could you explain that more in detail?What are the differences between the implicitly-declared constructor and the defaulted constructor.I would be grateful to have some help with this question.

Comment: A special member is implicitly-declared if it isn't written. A defaulted special member is one that is declared with `= default`